# Добавить регулярное выражение Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, selenium

Результат выглядит следующим образом : 7463 (+6.16%) Челмет - Югра П1 2.40
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сравнивать значение в скобках после знака "+"? То есть, что если процент выше например 10, то это нужно записать отдельно. Переменная называется b.text - "7463 (+6.16%)", если например +6.16% > 10% то подходит.  Спасибо.

```
from selenium import webdriver


def get_data(url):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python26\Chromedriver')
        driver.implicitly_wait(7)
        driver.get(url)
        page = 1
        while page < 10:

            content = driver.find_element_by_id('dle-content')

            for c in content.find_elements_by_class_name('news_boxing'):
                for b in c.find_elements_by_class_name('stats'):
                    if '+' in b.text:
                        try:
                            match = c.find_element_by_class_name("commands")
                            stavka = c.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="prediction"]//div[@class="info_match"]')
                            kf = c.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="prediction"]//a[@class="hover_block"]')
                            print(b.text, match.text, stavka.text, kf.text)
                        except:
                            continue
            next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="next"]').click()
            page += 1
    except:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    finally:
        driver.quit()




def main():
    url = 'https://vprognoze.ru/'
    print(get_data((url)))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Почитайте описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]: надо привести конкретные примеры текстов и что в них надо найти

Comment: не понятно в какой переменной находится ваше "7463 (+6.16%) Челмет - Югра П1 2.40"

Comment: извиняюсь, сейчас обновлю

Comment: @Skazalasobaka из текста `7463 (+6.16%)` надо найти `6.16`, так? Если да, то уточните, сколько разрядов у этих чисел (до запятой и после), может ли быть `-` вместо `+` и так далее. Надо сделать однозначное условие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
import re
s = "7463 (+6.12%) Челмет - Югра П1 2.40"
res = float(re.findall("([+-]\d+[.]\d+)%", s)[0])
```

Это самый постой вариант. Здесь просто получаются все цифры между `+` и `%` и преобразуются в `float`.

Вот более полный вариант:

```
import re

s = "7463 (+6.12%) Челмет - Югра П1 2.40"
res = -1.0

try:
    res = float(re.findall("([+-]\d+[.]\d+)%", s)[0])
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid number format")


if res > 10:
    print("Result is", res)
else:
    print("Result is less than 10")
```

На всякий случай обернул в `try/except` (вдруг что-то пойдёт не так `:)`).

Вариант выше работает, если из строки нужно получить только одно число (как у вас в примере). То есть, если будет что-то вроде

> 7463 (+6.12%) Челмет (+12.24%) - Югра П1 2.40

то вы получите только `6.12`

---

А этот код вытащит все значения в скобках между `+` и `%` и переведёт их в `float`.

```
import re

s = "7463 (+6.12%) (+7.12%) Челмет (+8.12%) - Югра П1 (+9.12%)2.40"
raw_res = re.findall("([+-]\d+[.]\d+)%", s)
res = []


for i in raw_res:
    try:
        res.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        print("Number", i, "is invalid")

print(res)
#=> [6.12, 7.12, 8.12, 9.12]
```

Дальше пользуйтесь как хотите, теперь `res` список чисел `float`.

Comment: У вас странная регулярка. Например, она найдёт `|9000.9000%`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот (знаки +-, одна или две цифры после знака, опциональные точка и N цифр после неё):

```
^\d+\s\([+-]\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?%\)$
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/CYVANM/2

Сгенерированный код:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^\d+\s\([+-]\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?%\)$"

test_str = ("7463 (+6.16%)\n"
    "11 (-5%)\n"
    "255 (+42.5%)")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```